# Distinguish td's using javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table, tablerow, tablecell

I am creating a table, two rows, and two cells in each row in my code. For this purpose, I've got the following code:

```
var t = document.createElement('table');
document.body.appendChild(t);
for (var x = 0; x <= 1; x++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    t.appendChild(tr);
    for (var y = 0; y <= 1; y++) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
}
```

Now, I need to create a text node in the first cell and create a `a` element in the second cell. How would I do that?

Comment: `if`'s, with `if`'s yes

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: I have problems seeing why this is such a hard challenge that you need to put it on SO? or my knowledge is so big that I can't reach such problems anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var t = document.createElement('table');
document.body.appendChild(t);
for (var x = 0; x <= 1; x++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    t.appendChild(tr);
    for (var y = 0; y <= 1; y++) {

        var td = document.createElement('td');
        tr.appendChild(td);

        if(y == 0){
            alert("here");
            var a = document.createElement('A');
            td.appendChild(a);
            alert("here");
        }
        else{
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            td.appendChild(div);
            //Create text node
        }
    }
}
```

Inside your loop check if `y == 0`, if it is then you are at your first `td` therefore you create a link.
If `y == 1` you are at the second `td` therefore  you create textnode

Replace `div` with whatever you want.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually more code to do a "two-step" loop, than to write it out in full:

```
var t = document.createElement('table'),
    trs = [document.createElement('tr'),document.createElement('tr')],
    tds = [
        [document.createElement('td'),document.createElement('td')],
        [document.createElement('td'),document.createElement('td')]
    ];
trs[0].appendChild(tds[0][0]);    trs[0].appendChild(tds[0][1]);
trs[1].appendChild(tds[1][0]);    trs[1].appendChild(tds[1][1]);
t.appendChild(trs[0]);            t.appendChild(trs[1]);
// now append more stuff here to the tds
document.body.appendChild(t); // do this last - it's better
```

Comment: Why so complicated D:

Answer (score 0):

inside your second loop just check for if (y == 0) then create text inside the td and if (y == 1) then create an a inside the td.

Answer (score 0):

another way would be to just define the table in text.

eg:

```
var t = document.createElement('table');
t.innerHTML = "<tr><td>text</td><td><a href='#'>link</a></td></tr><tr><td>text</td><td><a href='#'>link</a></td></tr>";
```